# django: where to find models field type translation to postgres

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to compare the table of a given database with an app's model definitions.

```
class SewManAbstract(models.Model):
   """
   """
   display_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   code = models.CharField(
       max_length=100, blank=True,
       help_text='txt')
   length = models.FloatField(_("length"), null=True, help_text='input')
```

When I query the database directly for metadata, I get

```
meta = ([u'display_name', u'character varying(255)', 
     u'code', u'character varying(100)', 
     u'length', u'double precision'])
```

When I use django's build-in functionality

```
FieldNameType = collections.namedtuple(
    "FieldNameType", 'field_name, field_type')
tmp = []
for field in model._meta.local_fields:
    fn = FieldNameType(
        field.name, model._meta.
            get_field(field.name).get_internal_type())
    tmp.append(fn)
```

I get

```
[FieldNameType(field_name='display_name', field_type=u'CharField'), 
FieldNameType(field_name='code', field_type=u'CharField'),
FieldNameType(field_name='length', field_type=u'FloatField')]
```

Comparing the two different outputs won't be easy. So my question really is: where can I find django's internal translation of a model field type to the corresponding postgres field type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this translation in [this module](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0ed7d155635da9f79d4dd67e4889087d3673c6da/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py) (**django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base**) in *DatabaseWrapper* class's *data_types* attribute.

Comment: do you also know how i can access the dict?

Comment: @LarsVegas What version of django and python are you using?

Comment: Django 1.6 with python 2.7

Comment: In Django 1.6 this dict is inside another module. after "from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.creation import DatabaseCreation" you can access this dict with "DatabaseCreation.data_types".